# Como fazer a média de registros por dia em PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá

Eu queria saber como faço pra poder contar a média de usuários criados por dia.

Por exemplo:

SEGUNDA 
Média de 3 clientes
TERÇA
Média de 4 clientes
QUARTA
Média de 3 clientes

e por dia

ÚLTIMOS SETE DIAS
temos uma média de 5 clientes criados por dia.

Não faço ideia de onde começar.

Atualmente para contar a quantidade de clientes eu uso esse código:

```
//Selecionar todos os clientes da tabela
$query = "SELECT * FROM `clientes`";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

//Contar o total de cursos
$total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer selecionar os registros dos últimos 7 dias, suponto que a sua tabela tenha um campo chamado "data_cadastro", você pode contar o total de registros e fazer a média fazendo uma consulta como esta:

```
SELECT count(*) as total, (count(*) / 7) as media FROM clientes where data_cadastro > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Em relação aos dias da semana, você precisaria alinhar o conceito. Você quer a media dos cadastros feitos em todas as segundas-feiras? Aqui tem um exemplo de como contar todos os cadastros feitos nas segundas

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM clientes where WEEKDAY(data_cadastro) = 0
```

Aqui tem a explicação de como funciona esta função.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_weekday.asp

Você poderia pegar este resultado e dividir pela quantidade de segundas-feiras do período que você quer filtrar.

Aqui tem uma postagem que comenta algo assim

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569956/get-number-of-monday-in-a-rangedate-mysql

Comment: Como teria que estar o campo DATA? pois eu fiz de acordo com que você falou e só me resulta no número 1

Comment: desde já agradeço pela ajuda